# What am I: Song

Tags: riddle, music

> Beside the place, where water flows,
>   Where flora at the surface grows,
>   Something is there, or is it really?
>   All I can say, my rhymes are silly

What song am I?

Hint 1:

> The poem describes some lyrics, not the name of the song

Comment: I think this needs the KNOWLEDGE tag, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The song is

> The Riddle

by

> Nik Kershaw

Which I note is rather

> appropriate given the context of this site!

This part of the poem:

> Beside the place, where water flows,
>
> Where flora at the surface grows,
>
> Something is there, or is it really?

Refers to:

> The lyrics of the refrain: "Near the tree by the river there's a hole in the ground". The river is the flowing water, the tree is the flora, and the "something" that is there, or maybe not, is the hole --- after all, is a hole not defined by something *not* being there?

The final line, "All I can say, my rhymes are silly" could refer to

> the generally cryptic nature of the lyrics, with plenty of poetic expressions but little easily observable meaning. Kershaw himself has called the lyrics "nonsense".

Answer (score 4):

The Song is

> "Bluegrass Break" by the Lilly Brothers

"Beside the place, where water flows"

> Where water flows is BLUE.

"Where flora at the surface grows"

> GRASS is a kind of flora

"Something is there, or is it really?"

> A BREAK is an interruption, an absence. Yet we refer to it as exiting, though it is nothing

"All I can say, my rhymes are silly"

> LILLY rhymes with silly.

Comment: Now that I read that solution, I think it's much better than what I had in mind, but not the one I meant